# How to thank someone in different ways?

Tags: learning, greetings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can somebody explain the various words and combinations thereof used for thanking?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/438/can-somebody-explain-the-various-words-and-combinations-thereof-used-for-thanking)

There are numerous ways of saying thanks. To give the ones I know:

- ありがとう
- ありがとうございます
- どうも

Are there other ways? And, if so, how would one discern when to use them?

Also, how can I thank someone for something *specifically*? As in, "Thank you for the cake." 「ケーキ[something]ありがとうございます」. Would such a phrase be culturally appropriate in most situations, or are there nuances?

Comment: See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/438/can-somebody-explain-the-various-words-and-combinations-thereof-used-for-thanking/442#442 and other answers on that page.

Comment: as for your second question: ケーキありがとう works.