# What does どうも do when added to ありがとう or ありがとうございます?

Tags: meaning, nuances

What does どうも do when added to ありがとう and ありがとうございます?

What is nuance behind the どうもありがとう and どうもありがとうございます that's created?

Is it just more polite/humble? Or is there some more at play?

Also, slightly off topic, but could the polite prefix お be used with these?
Is おどうもありがとうございます valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding どうも makes the sentence stronger, like adding "(Thank you) very much".

While ありがとうございます is undoubtedly more polite than ありがとう (like "thank you" is undoubtedly more polite than "thanks"), adding どうも may not make the sentence more polite, strictly speaking. Saying ありがとうございます without どうも is polite enough when you talk with your superior. That said, when you talk with your superior, it's of course a good idea to emphasize your appreciation by adding どうも.

Do not add the prefix お. おどうもありがとうございます sounds really funny.

See Also: [Can somebody explain the various words and combinations thereof used for thanking?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/438/5010)